# How can I emulate UPDATE x SET (col1, col2) = ( SELECT a,b FROM y ) in Derby?

Tags: sql, sql-update, derby

Derby doesn't support this syntax:

```
UPDATE x SET (col1, col2, ...) = ( SELECT a,b,... FROM y ... )
```

(see [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-4074)). Does anyone have a workaround other than creating a loop in Java which does the select and sends N updates back?

**[EDIT]** Note that I have 50 columns and a complex condition (joins with x and EXISTS and whatnot). So I'dd like to avoid repeating the SELECT 50 times, please :)

Answer (score 2):

I too would do it the was rbobby siad but I'm also a MSSQL person.

Have you tried:

```
UPDATE x 
SET (col1)= ( SELECT a FROM y where y.fkfield = x.pkidfield),
(col21)= ( SELECT b FROM y where y.fkfield = x.pkidfield), )
```

Comment: Yes; the problem here is that I have 50 columns and a complex SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's valid sql (I'm more a MS SQL guy so I could be way way off).

Normally I'd do:

```
update Orders
set Orders.Code = OtherOrders.Code,
    Orders.Name = OtherOrders.Name
from Orders inner join Orders as OtherOrders 
    on OtherOrders.OrderId = Orders.OrderId
```

Comment: Unfortunately, FROM is not allowed in UPDATE statements :(